# Proving transitive based on elements in relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I was reading my notes when i came across some transitive proofing which i can't understand. For example

> A = {0, 1, 2} and let R be a relation on given by
>
> R = {(0,0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 0)}

So this is how my notes do some transitive proofing which is rather weird

> (0, 0), (0, 1) ∈ R, so (0, 1) should be in R, which it is
>
> (1, 1), (1, 0) ∈ R, so (1, 0) should be in R, which it is
>
> (0, 1), (1, 1) ∈ R, so (0, 1) should be in R, which it is
>
> (0, 1), (1, 0) ∈ R, so (0, 0) should be in R, which it is
>
> (1, 0), (0, 1) ∈ R, so (1, 1) should be in R, which it is
>
> (1, 0), (0, 0) ∈ R, so (1, 0) should be in R, which it is
>
> Therefore R is a transitive

Here is the question, how do they exactly derive the information that produce that 6 statements? What about the other elements in the relation such as `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)`?

Comment: You could if you wanted to add $(1,1)$ and $(1,1)\in R$ so $(1,1)$ should be in $R$, but that sounds rather redundant...  The point is, anywhere you can get to via a chain of relations, you should also have a shortcut to get there as well.  It is often written as "if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ then you must have $x\sim z$" (*note that $x,y,z$ need not be unique*) but you could extend this via induction to the statement "If $a_1\sim a_2\sim\dots\sim a_n$ then you must have $a_1\sim a_n$"

Comment: The "proof" in your notes brute force checked every triple $(x,y,z)$ such that $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ where at least one of $x\neq y$ or $y\neq z$ to check to verify that $x\sim z$.  It opted not to check $x\sim x$ and $x\sim x$ to verify that $x\sim x$, because again, it is rather redundant.  It was a lot of words to prove something which could be verified visually for yourself in an instant.  Proving something like this *is* transitive is a lot more wordy than proving that it isn't (just find a counterexample).  Later examples, $R$ will be kinder, like $\subseteq$ or $\leq$ or $\mid$.

Comment: Frankly, I think that $(0,0),(0,1)\in R, (1,1),(1,0)\in R$ and $(1,0),(0,0)\in R$ are also redundant.  If $(x,x),(x,y)\in R$ of course $(x,y)\in R$... it was one of the hypotheses.

Comment: then what do you think should be the approperiate way to prove that it is a transivity. It seems like that portion of my notes are too wordy and it becomes confusing for a student like me. I'm also confused like how they get this 6 statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are interested in these six statements in particular is that transitivity says "if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$, then $(x,z) \in R$".
Note here that $y$ is a common, connecting variable between the two pairs. Thus, we only need to consider those pairs that have such a common variable. This means that it makes sense to consider $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ together, because they are connected through $0$, but there is no reason to consider $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ together, for example,
because they are not connected through $1$ and $2$. If you want to be extremely pedantic (but please don't), then you would also have to consider that if $(1,1) \in R$ and $(1,1) \in R$, then $(1,1) \in R$, but this is too obvious to merit mention.

Comment: Bingo. That solves all my doubt. Thanks a lot. At least now i really do understand why they chose those particular elements because they have a common connective while the others don't. As for the obvious ones which you mentioned, they technically means the same but of course for exam reason, I guess i still need to write it out just in case the lecturer is kinda anal over it. but still thanks a lot :D